# Move the Search box in the end of the navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar, bootstrap-5

I want to move the search icon and search input at the end of the navbar.
I'm using Bootstrap 5.0.2
IDK how to move the icon and search box at the end as I'm new to Bootstrap, HTML, and CSS as well.
also i dont want to increase the size of the search box i want its width to be 50% if i make the width to 100% the search box and icon will go in the end but i **want its width to be 50%** and keep both of them in the end

```css
.Banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75%;
  position: fixed;
  background-image: url(/NavBar/Img.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.icon-white {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cont:hover .cube {
  color: black;
}

#searchform {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Linux Coder</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">

  <!-- Bootstrap -->

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Bootstrap Icons -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.4/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- container -->
  <div class="container-fluid bg-dark" style="height: 1000px;">

    <!-- navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark row">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Linux Coder</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">BLOGS</a>

            </li>

            <!-- Search box -->

          </ul>
          <form id="#searchform" class="d-flex">
            <input style="width: 50%;" class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-light cont" type="submit"><i class="cube bi bi-search icon-white"></i></button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <hr style="color: white; margin: 0;">

    <!-- javascript -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

I want to move the search input and search icon to the end of the navbar

Comment: adding spam and even labeling it as such to bypass the minimum requirement filter is not allowed and can be punished! The filter exists for reasons and you rather should add actual details rather than try to bypass the filter with nonsense. Check your markup, you missing at least 1 closing tag!

Comment: `id="#searchform" ` is incorrect, should not have a `#` in the `id=`

Comment: @Ron thanks for the correction but the searbox and icon is still not in the end of the navbar

Answer (score 5):

remove the `style="width: 50%"` from the input of your search bar. It causes the container to be twice as large then the input while the search icon is smaller than the input. That caused the white-space.

As you said within the comment that you want `width: 50%` on the input, you could also use the class `ms-auto` on the input to move all elements to the end of the flexbox container:

```css
.Banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75%;
  position: fixed;
  background-image: url(/NavBar/Img.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.icon-white {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cont:hover .cube {
  color: black;
}

#searchform {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Linux Coder</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">

  <!-- Bootstrap -->

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Bootstrap Icons -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.4/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- container -->
  <div class="container-fluid bg-dark" style="height: 1000px;">

    <!-- navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark row">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Linux Coder</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">BLOGS</a>

            </li>

            <!-- Search box -->

          </ul>
          <form id="#searchform" class="d-flex">
            <input style="width: 50%;" class="form-control me-2 ms-auto" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-light cont" type="submit"><i class="cube bi bi-search icon-white"></i></button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <hr style="color: white; margin: 0;">

    <!-- javascript -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .Banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75%;
  position: fixed;
  background-image: url(/NavBar/Img.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.icon-white {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cont:hover .cube {
  color: black;
}

#searchform {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Linux Coder</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">

  <!-- Bootstrap -->

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Bootstrap Icons -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.4/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- container -->
  <div class="container-fluid bg-dark" style="height: 1000px;">

    <!-- navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark row">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Linux Coder</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">BLOGS</a>

            </li>

            <!-- Search box -->

          </ul>
          <form id="#searchform" class="d-flex">
            <input class="form-control me-2 ms-auto" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-light cont" type="submit"><i class="cube bi bi-search icon-white"></i></button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <hr style="color: white; margin: 0;">

    <!-- javascript -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Immediate child elements of .navbar use flex layout and will default to justify-content: space-between. Use additional flex utilities as needed to adjust this behavior.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/
You can use flex property in the same way of css, justify-self property is what u need I think

Comment: The default of `justify-content` is `start` not `space-between`. It is not a flexbox issue beyond the fact that the Bootstrap 5 navbar is already using flexbox. It's a width issue with the search bar (see my answer and snippet). I highly advise you to use a [repro] to validate your answers yourself

Comment: @tacoshy i want to width to be 50% only i want everything to be just how it is in the code just i want to position to be adjusted the move them in the end

Comment: Oh ok, sorry and thank you, it's my first answer, next time I'll use snippets too

Comment: @VirajS you commented on the wrong answer, but I edited your answer to also work with `width: 50%`